# Soap webservice query

Tags: android, web-services

I am trying a simple soap webservice example.
I added the ksoap2 jar file but still i am getting "The import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject cannot be resolved"....
Please help me

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020740/how-do-i-import-jars-in-an-android-project

Comment: hey ur problem solved or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all just make a folder libs.

Copy and paste .jar files.

Goto properties-->Java Build Path-->Libraries. Here just import from yourproject/lib and press OK.

Comment: It's recommended that the lib folder to be called "libs", not lib or you might encounter problems with different tools.

Comment: I agree. I had problem with jar in lib folder. It's from android sdk r16 or r17 when jars should be in libs folder

Answer (score 3):

You add any Jar-files to your project like this:

1. Open your project's properties (right click)
2. Choose 'Java Build Path'
3. Choose 'Libraries' tab
4. Click 'Add External Jar' button
5. Find and choose *.jar file.

download [ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/#svn/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.6.4)

[here](http://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.6.4/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) a direct link to it